Road texture is blurred where camera is far
I am trying to develop a car race game using JavaFX. I am using perspective camera. I am using PointLight as well. The road gets blurred where the camera is far. How can I avoid this blurring? My camera settings are below:
PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
camera.setNearClip(5);
camera.setFarClip(1000);
camera.setFieldOfView(20);

PointLight pointLight = new PointLight(Color.WHITE); 
pointLight.setTranslateY(-500);
root3D.getChildren().add(pointLight);
pointLight.translateXProperty().bind(cameraPosition.xProperty());
pointLight.translateZProperty().bind(cameraPosition.zProperty());

SubScene subScene = new SubScene(root3D, 1920, 1080, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
subScene.setCamera(camera);



The image looks like poor quality (or no) Anisotropic filtering.  I don't have a suggestion on how you fix that for your application.

Default field of view is 30 try to tweak that value

Ok, when I disabled Anti-aliasing using:
SubScene subScene = new SubScene(root3D, 1920, 1080, true, SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED);


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

In order to debug the visual artifact you are seeing (the blurring at distance) we would need to see how you are adding the landscape, road and road lines to the scene. I am assuming you are achieving a road animation effect using a material animation but we need to see that mechanic too.
If your road or lines are separate 3D shapes with semi transparent materials then the order they are added to the scene will determine some transparency effects. Just guessing here. Need much more info.
